# Start keyframe animation when transition finished (CSS)

Tags: css

I would like to ask for help with implementing my idea: as soon as *image1* finishes its transition, the "*anim*" animation will start.

**What i tried:**

I tried make it with "*animation-delay*" but this is not my option - the point is that "*animation-delay*" adds a time before execution after a mouse click, I need animation to start immediately after the end of the transition. If it's not clear, I'll put it more simply: when you click and little bit hold many times *image1*, the transition does not start over, but the "animation-delay" starts over after last mouse click.

```css
.image2{
  top:0px;
  left:300px;
  position: absolute;
}
.image1{
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.image1:active{
  transform: scale(0.6);
}

.image1:active + .image2{
  animation: anim 2s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0%   {top:0%;}
  100% {top:20%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<img class="image1" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/p/6/C/i/q/run-button-md.png">
<img class="image2" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gti0MtNnT1rEQOuo9mfPfegw-qRGLI1MS3QqamM243fVcIXWqJHmlwldYpBJAwsd3tkQtIfvBqernahhDjuzSw=s200">
</div>
```

**Thanks for any help!**

Comment: Is it OK to use a little Javascript? You probaby need to listen for two events, transitionend on the first image and animationend on the second image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a bit of JS is OK, you can sense when the transition of image1 ends and then start the animation of image2. But you also need to sense the end of this animation so you can reset it and next time it will play again (otherwise CSS thinks it's done it and won't replay it).

```js
const test = document.querySelector('.test');
const image1 = document.querySelector('.image1');
const image2 = document.querySelector('.image2');

image1.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
  image2.classList.add('active');  
});

image2.addEventListener('animationend', function () {
  image2.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.image2{
  top:0px;
  left:300px;
  position: absolute;
}
.image1{
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.image1:active{
  transform: scale(0.6);
}

.image2.active{
  animation: anim 2s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0%   {top:0%;}
  100% {top:20%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<img class="image1" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/p/6/C/i/q/run-button-md.png">
<img class="image2" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gti0MtNnT1rEQOuo9mfPfegw-qRGLI1MS3QqamM243fVcIXWqJHmlwldYpBJAwsd3tkQtIfvBqernahhDjuzSw=s200">
</div>
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot!** Yes, bit of JS is okay, the fact is that I don't know much about JS. The only thing I would like to ask is why does the animation start 2 times in a row? Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `transitionend` event and then add a class that starts the keyframe animation.

CSS

```
.animationclass {
    animation: anim 2s;
 }
```

JS

```
const img1 = document.querySelector('.image1');

img1.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
     console.log('Transition ended, add keyframe animation')
     img1.classList.add("animationclass")
});
```